# How do I get data out of the iOS advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] object?

Tags: ios, ads, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
I used this code:

func centralManager(centralManager: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
        let scannedPeripheral = (peripheral, advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey])
        peripherals.append(scannedPeripheral)
        print(advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]!)
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

to upload a BLE peripheral object and it's corresponding `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]` object to an iOS phone.  I store both objects as a tuple in a `[peripheral, anyObject?]` array.  When I print the `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]` object in the console I see this:

```
{
    "91765580-D821-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" = <8df0>;
}
```

which is supposed to be an `NSDictionary` with a `CBUUID` key, and an `NSData` value.  The information is exactly what I need but I can't get at it to use in my program.  Any ideas on how to break this data out?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?  Accessing the bytes in the NSData?

Comment: Yes.  That's the problem, from what I understand the object containing that line {
    "91765580-D821-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" = <8df0>;
}
I want to break out the long UUIDD and use and also use the 0x8df0.  Hope you can help.  Thanks.

Comment: The UUID is the key for the dictionary (CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey) and the value is an NsData instance. Just use the key to access to dictionary and get the value `as! NSData`

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion worked.  But is there a way that I can dig out BOTH the UUID dictionary key string AND the data, which for this particular peripheral transmission is 8df0, without having to use the dictionary key?  The reason for this is that the iOS device may not always have the key beforehand.  So if the peripheral is transmitting both the key and the data, and I can easily see/store them both in the advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] can I get them both out another way other than having to use the key?  Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't know what the key is then you can access it using the `allKeys` method of the dictionary or in swift you can enumerate the array into a tupple `for (key,data) in dictionary {`

Comment: Thanks much.  You've been very helpful.  Now I am trying to use the NSData object <8df0> which has been returned in this case from the dictionary.  Even when I remove the angle brackets an prefix a 0x I don't seem to be able to use it in an If statement or compare it's equivalency  to another value, etc.  How can I get to down to that hex number 0x8df0?  Thanks again.

Comment: You can use the getBytes method of NSData to access the bytes. What you see when you print the data is just the output of the description method, which is only intended for logging/debugging.

Comment: What does the code look like to get that data out with that key?  I assume the key is the long UUID string.  I can't figure it out.   I assumed it was something like let dictionary = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] then using a key CBUUID representing that UUID string, call it cbuuid,  the code would look like: let  nsData = dictionary[cbuuid].  Thanks for an code you can provide.